# Gmail contextual gadget - What is the updated way to create?

Tags: xml, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, gmail, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I want to develop an in-house contextual gadget for gmail.
The problem is that Google changed the way to do that. It began on November 2013, and in October 2014 the old way entirely depracated.

So:

Which web page should I follow?

Which Google service should I use?

Does `in-house contextual gadget` still exist, or maybe it has been depracated?

**Examples:**

The `Google Apps Engine` (GAE) in `code.google.com/googleapps/console` doesn't let me deploy the application since it requires `OAuth 2.0`. Am I supposed to use `developers console` (in `console.developers.google.com`)?

There is a web page `https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets`. Is it updated?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue.  I believe that the problem is that OAuth 2.0 is now required, and all of the sample Contextual Gadgets out there have no OAuth built into the gadget spec.  When you attempt to publish the manifest, it checks the gadget spec to see if it uses OAuth 2.0, and if the gadget spec does not, it assumes that you are using 1.0 and does not allow the gadget to be published.  At least, that is my best theory about what is going on.  

I am not sure how to implement OAuth 2.0, but I think no gadget spec will publish without OAuth 2.0 authentication built into it.

Comment: @MSD Do you think that by clicking on `delpy application` google apps searches for gadget spec's validation? What happens if the gadget spec file doesn't still exist, or if I change it after deploying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same issue and searched all over the place.

The way described at https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets seems to be totally outdated. Even the form in the Google Apps console for gadgets seems to be outdated.

You need to follow this description: https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/preparing

Contextual Gadgets are now developed using the API console (not app console) and there is a form to create the extractors etc.